# Google Charts "select" event firing multiple times

Tags: google-visualization

I am using a Column chart from the Google Visualization API, and have set up a "click" event for when I click on one of my columns as so:

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(event) {
    if (!isWebview) { 
        log.logInfo("Selected Sum");
        $("#reportBody").trigger("app:update", { toXYZ: true});
    } else { 
    }
});
```

However, this fires 4 times every time that I select a bar in the chart. This also happens to be the amount of rows that I have in the chart - could this be connected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you please share the rest of the code, is the event added for each row or something?

Comment: I found the reason, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:
I found the problem - there were two. Firstly, the html file for this js file loaded the same js code twice - once for ios and once for android, but on the browser loads both, thus adding the same event listeners twice.
Furthermore, both these ways of setting the `onLoad` callback were used:

```
google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {
'packages': ['corechart', 'table'],
'callback': drawAll
});
```

and

`google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAll);`

The latter of which is a deprecated version if I'm not mistaken.

Therefore, the `drawAll` function, which creates the event listener, ended up being called 4 times, so I had 4 event listeners for the same event, all executing the same code.